# Azure Help: Your sign-in was blocked

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

When I try to sign in to the Azure Portal, I get the following error:

Your sign-in was blocked We've detected something unusual about this sign-in. For example, you might be signing in from a new location, device, or app. Before you can continue, we need to verify your identity. Please contact your admin.

The problem is **I am the admin**. How do I get back into my account??

Comment: Did you tried from some other machine, laptop or mobile?

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation:

> To unlock your account, follow the instructions on the sign-in screen
>   and select where we can send you a security code. After you've
>   received the code, enter it to access your account.

There should be the possibility for you to login based on Microsoft sending a code as an SMS to your phone.

Comment: There's no option to have it send me a code. This is what I see:

[email]
Your sign-in was blocked
We've detected something unusual about this sign-in. For example, you might be signing in from a new location, device, or app. Before you can continue, we need to verify your identity. Please contact your admin.

Comment: If you contact your administrator, send this info to them.
Copy info to clipboard
Request Id: 6f91ab1d-e40d-445d-9d48-017ebc84c600
Correlation Id: c086bbb2-ec68-43f8-85fd-07b6d1d80b94
Timestamp: 2020-05-24T19:43:17.907Z
App name: Azure Portal
App id: c44b4083-3bb0-49c1-b47d-974e53cbdf3c
IP address: 97.115.113.213
Device identifier: Not available
Device platform: macOS
Device state: Unregistered
Advanced diagnostics: Enable
If you plan on getting support for an issue, turn this on and try to reproduce the error. This will collect additional information that will help...

Comment: What kind of account do you have? Do you have your own instance of Azure Active Directory?

Comment: I guess so? Whatever happens when you create a new Azure account and start using it.